# Flickable + property alias contents

Tags: qml, flickable

I've noticed a strange behavior with inheriting `Flickable`.

I have two files, `Comp.qml` and `main.qml`. The idea is that any children of a `Comp` object will be children of the `Flickable` under `Comp`. I've defaulted the contents using

```
default property alias contents: flickable.children
```

but the results turn out to be strange.

**Comp.qml**

```
Rectangle {
    id: comp;
    anchors.fill: parent

    default property alias contents: flickable.children;  // alias a default property
    property int contentHeight: comp.height;

    Flickable {
        id: flickable;
        anchors.fill: parent;
        contentHeight: comp.contentHeight;
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
Rectangle {
    id: root;
    width: 400;
    height: 400;

    Comp {
        contentHeight: 800;


        Rectangle {         //  <-- this rectangle should be a child of Flickable
            width: 800;
            height: 800;
            border.color: "black";
            border.width: 5;
            Component.onCompleted: console.debug(parent)
        }
    }
}
```

The flickable doesn't work.

If I try to put it all in one file, it work as expected :

**main.qml**

```
Rectangle {
    id: root;
    width: 400;
    height: 400;

    Rectangle {
        id: comp;
        anchors.fill: parent

        Flickable {
            id: flickable;
            anchors.fill: parent;
            contentHeight: 800;

            Rectangle {   //   <-- the child component
                width: 800;
                height: 800;
                border.color: "black";
                border.width: 5;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? How do I add an external component into a `Flickable`?

Comment: It looks than QML bind children item to  flickable before it was initialized. if you do `onContentsChanged: {flickable.contentWidth}` on `comp` you will get *-1*. But this `Rectangle` is 800px width. So may be it is size problem wile reparenting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#contentItem-prop):

> Items declared as children of a Flickable are automatically parented
>   to the Flickable's **contentItem**.
>   Items created dynamically need to be **explicitly parented** to the contentItem

That's not the first case here, i.e. the `Rectangle` got parented to the `Flickable` itself and does not expose the expected behaviour. Possibly, the addition to the `children` does not trigger the correct parenting, in this case. As a quick fix you can re-parent the item as soon as it is added to the `Comp` type.

To handle multiple `Item`s inside your `Comp` just use a unique child (a la `ScrollView`). Here I modified the example to handle two `Rectangle`s (just added `clip` to `Comp`, for aesthetic purposes).

In the main:

```
Rectangle {
    id: root;
    width: 400;
    height: 400;

    Comp {
        contentHeight: col.height;

        Column {
            id: col
            spacing: 20
            Rectangle {
                width: 800;
                height: 800;
                border.color: "black";
                border.width: 5;
            }

            Rectangle {
                width: 800;
                height: 800;
                border.color: "black";
                border.width: 5;
            }
        }

        Component.onCompleted: console.debug(col.parent) // <-- not flickable
    }
}
```

In the `Comp.qml` file:

```
Rectangle {
    id: comp;
    anchors.fill: parent
    default property alias contents: flickable.children;
    property int contentHeight: comp.height;

    Flickable {
        z:1
        clip: true       // just my taste!
        id: flickable;
        anchors.fill: parent;
        contentHeight: comp.contentHeight;
    }

    onContentsChanged: {                             // re-parenting
        if(flickable.children[1] !== undefined)
            flickable.children[1].parent = flickable.contentItem
    }
}
```